# How to using angular ng-view keeps content in input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and working on a small project. I want to build an editable table for courses including course Id and course Name. Users are able to click edit button and then they can edit content.

Howwever,I met a problem that when user clicks edit button, all the content just gone, like delete, but I want to keep the content editable. I try ng-value, but didn't work.

Here is my code and codepen link: http://codepen.io/marong125/pen/JRBQdo

Thank you so much!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Online Learning</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('app', []);
            app.controller('courseController', function ($scope) {
              $scope.courses = [
                  {
                      courseID: "CS602",
                      courseName: "Web Development",
                      isEditing:false
                  },
                  {
                      courseID: "CS502",
                      courseName: "Foundation of Java",
                      isEditing:false
                  }
              ];

                 $scope.addCourse = ()=>{
                     $scope.courses.push({
                         courseID: $scope.createIdInput,
                         courseName: $scope.createCourseInput
                     });
                     $scope.createIdInput = '';
                     $scope.createCourseInput = '';
                     console.log(1);
                 }
                 $scope.onEditClick = (course)=>{
                      course.isEditing = true;
                 }
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app">
        <<h1>Course Manager</h1>
    <div ng-controller = "courseController">
        <form name="courseForm">
            <input id="c_id_input"  placeholder="Add course ID" ng-model="createIdInput" />
            <input id= "c_name_input"  placeholder="Add course name" ng-model="createCourseInput" />
            <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" ng-click="addCourse()">Add Course</button>
        </form>

        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>Course ID</th>
                <th>Course Name</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat = "course in courses">
                <td>
                    <span ng-if="!course.isEditing" >{{course.courseID}}</span>
                    <form ng-submit="updateTask(course)">
                        <input type="text" ng-if="course.isEditing" class="form-control"
                               ng-value="course.courseID" ng-model="updatedCourseId" />
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span ng-if="!course.isEditing">{{course.courseName}}</span>
                    <form >
                        <input ng-if="course.isEditing" class="form-control"
                               ng-value="course.courseName" ng-model="updatedCourseName" />
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="onEditClick(course)" >Edit</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of your ng-model in the edit fields. If you look closely you will find that ng-model for your ID field in updatedCourseId and Name is updatedCourseName. However your actual values are stored in course.courseID and course.courseName. Change your ng-model and point to the correct variables.

```
<input type="text" ng-if="course.isEditing" class="form-control"
                           ng-value="course.courseID" ng-model="updatedCourseId" />

<input ng-if="course.isEditing" class="form-control"
                           ng-value="course.courseName" ng-model="updatedCourseName" />
```

**Alternatively**

If you don't want to mix up the updated value and the non-updated value you can do that by copying the current value to another field when the user clicks on edit. I have created a codepen to demonstrate this, you can see it [here](http://codepen.io/pratikb517/pen/jrpjoj).

JavaScript (Controller)

```
$scope.onEditClick = (course) => {
                  course.isEditing = true;
                  course.updatedCourseId = course.courseID;
                  course.updatedCourseName = course.courseName;
             }
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-if="course.isEditing" class="form-control"
                               ng-model="course.updatedCourseId" />
<input ng-if="course.isEditing" class="form-control"
                               ng-model="course.updatedCourseName" />
```

Comment: @partik Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding how `ng-model` works.  `ng-model` represents the variable that your data is saved in, and it's a two way binding.  You don't need a separate variable to store the "updated" values.

Instead of:

```
 <input type="text" ng-if="course.isEditing" class="form-control" 
                    ng-value="course.courseID" ng-model="updatedCourseId" />
```

you should use:

```
 <input type="text" ng-if="course.isEditing" class="form-control"
                    ng-model="course.courseID" />
```

The changes will automatically be reflected, in real time, back to the array.